# 'zinnia_loop_template' received too many positional arguments

Tags: python, django, zinnia

I am working on Django 1.8. I want to work with Django-blog-zinnia.
I have installed zinnia, changed my setting.py file and have added links in urls.py of project. when I tried to access zinnia using weblog as per mentioned on Installation site

> weblog

I got an error

> 'zinnia_loop_template' received too many positional arguments

I am new to it. Kindly tell me how to resolve this

This is my setting.py file
"""

> Django settings for newproject project.
>
> Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.
>
> For more information on this file, see
>
> For the full list of settings and their values, see
>
> ## Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...) import os
>
> BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**)))
>
> ## SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret! SECRET_KEY = 'f7p-j96!04oy!5wbuf&=g8vkm9deupxw9ywjq)+ef8wfjy=5s('
>
> ## SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production! DEBUG = True
>
> ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
>
> ## Application definition
>
> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>       'django.contrib.admin',
>       'django.contrib.auth',
>       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>       'django.contrib.sessions',
>       'django.contrib.sites',
>       'django.contrib.messages',
>       'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>       'django_comments',
>       'mptt',
>       'tagging',
>       'zinnia', )
>
> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
>       'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>       'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
>       'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>       'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
>       'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', )
>
> ROOT_URLCONF = 'newproject.urls'
>
> TEMPLATES = [   {
>       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
>       'APP_DIRS': True,
>       'OPTIONS': {
>         'context_processors': [
>           'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
>           'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
>           'django.template.context_processors.request',
>           'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
>           'zinnia.context_processors.version',  # Optional
>         ]
>       }   } ]
>
> SITE_ID = 1
>
> WSGI_APPLICATION = 'newproject.wsgi.application'
>
> DATABASES = {
>       'default': {
>           'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
>           'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
>       } }
>
> LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
>
> TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
>
> USE_I18N = True
>
> USE_L10N = True
>
> USE_TZ = True
>
> STATIC_URL = '/static/'

This is my urls.py file

> from django.conf.urls import include, url
>   from django.contrib import admin
>
> ```
> urlpatterns = [     
>     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
>     url(r'^weblog/', include('zinnia.urls')),
>   url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
> ]
> ```

Comment: Please post your code, and the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

i also have this failure in django-blog-zinnia 0.17 with django 1.8 .
i assume, it's a bug, because it works with django-blog-zinnia 0.16;

pip install django-blog-zinnia==0.16

maybe it's because of the compatibility of django 1.9 since zinnia 0.17 - because i like to stay on django 1.8 for other website-parts, i just downgrade zinnia to 0.16 and it's ok for me, hope it helps you too.